Can it be illegal to encrypt data that would be illegal to delete?
From an earlier question in many jurisdictions it can be illegal to delete data that "may be required as evidence in a judicial proceeding" (Australia) or for the purpose of "pervert[ing] the course of public justice" (England and Wales, Canada).
Suppose in such a situation one did not delete the data, but encrypted it with a key that was known or knowable to a third party, perhaps at the destination when crossing a border.  Would that be illegal?
The sort of situation where this could be relevant is highlighted by the case of Ernest Moret where the refusal to provide information resulted in arrest on suspicion of wilfully obstructing a Schedule 7 examination.
An example way this could be implemented is below, I encrypt the password with the public key of my friend at my destination, allowing them only to decrypt it.  I then set that password as the key for the directory holding my secret files.  This would have the effect of rendering the data as decrytptable only with the collaboration of my friend.
To illustrate the overall objective of the operation imagine Ernest Moret had on his laptop a directory containing his journalistic contacts labelled folder_of_secrets.  If this was protected by a remembered password in either the UK or France then he could not be required to disclose that data without a warrant, that would require some suspicion of a crime.  While on the Eurostar between London and Paris he could be required to disclose this password and therefore the contacts without any suspicion of a crime.  Deleting the data could be a crime as detailed in the earlier question.
If he ran these command prior to crossing the border he would not be able to provide a password and may not be liable to prosecution for failing to answer a question he could.  He has not deleted any data so may not be liable as specified in the earlier question.
% gpg -e -a -r friend@destination > password.asc
complex_machine_generated_password

% encfsctl passwd ~/.folder_of_secrets
Enter current Encfs password
EncFS Password: old_password
Enter new Encfs password
New Encfs Password: complex_machine_generated_password
Verify Encfs Password: complex_machine_generated_password
Volume Key successfully updated.



The command-line output is unlikely to elucidate your question for people here. Instead describe the hypothetical facts in English.

@kaya3 I have explained what I am doing in the paragraph above the code block.  If it is unclear it would be good to know.

Either there is relevant information in the code block, in which case your question can only be answered by someone with expertise in both law and also command-line interfaces of encryption software; or otherwise, there is no relevant information in the code block. If the former, the relevant information should be rewritten in English so that more people can answer it. If the latter, the code block should be removed. People without expertise in encryption software (i.e. most people who could write an answer) cannot determine for themselves how important the code block is to the question.

@kaya3 The final paragraph of text and the code block effectively contain the same information.  The text should be useful to most people, and is probably sufficient to answer the question. The code block provides a specific example if the details of implementation matter, as the answer to many of these questions is "it depends".  Since I do not know the details of the law, I am incapable of determining the specificity required.

@kaya3 Actually the example is not necessary to the question, the first two paragraphs are complete in themselves.  It just frequently helps to have a concrete example of the general point one is trying to make.  A real world example where the problem arose, and a potential technical solution that may not be illegal seems to add to the completeness of the question.

It might be clear to you but it is not clear to others,. The purpose of not deleting the data is so that it can be used as evidence in whatever legal procedure that requires it. If you are asking if the data can be encrypted but later decrypted for use by the legal procedure that is one thing, however if you are asking if it can be encrypted so it can't be used that is another thing and similar to deletion.

@JoeW I did not know that was a critical point, but the answer is in the "code".  I have edited the text to answer this point.

It still doesn't make any sense at all, what is the goal of the encryption in the first place? Is it to keep the data from being accessed by the legal procedures?

The question is described in a very technical manner.  OP could have instead asked, "Can I password protect evidence? What if I intentionally use an un-memorizable password, then either don't write it down (nobody can recover the data) or mail it to a friend? (data is not recoverable without my friend's help)."

Yes
The offense in both jurisdictions is tampering with evidence which is a far broader set of acts and omission than merely deleting evidence. In particular, it captures concealing evidence as described.
